# How to change cell value according to sum

Tags: excel

I want to change cell value according to my sum means if i give total 2000 in "A5" than value change automatic in cell range A1 to A4.

Comment: Please show some test data and expected output in table format.

Comment: If you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

It's confusing to answer your question without knowing more.

Assuming you are working in Excel, if you have the following numbers

```
A1 A2 A3  A4  A5
5  6  7   8   1000
```

you can set the following formula for A1, A2, etc.

```
=IF($A$5=2000,*value that you want cells to read, "")
```

Essentially if the condition on cell A5 is met, in this case reaching 2000, you will change the value of cell A1 - A4 to a specified amount. If it doesn't reach 2000, you will keep the original value.

Answer (score 0):

You could have formulas in A1 to A4 as percentages of A5,

for example,

`A1: =0.1*A5`

`A2: =0.2*A5`

`A3: =0.3*A5`

`A4: =0.4*A5`